# How can calayer frame be slow, and what can we do to optimize it?

Tags: ios, core-animation

(UIView*).frame is taking 10% (!) of total app time, and I have no idea why. I haven't overridden the default method, and frankly ".frame" ought to be lightning fast, no?

Instruments is not giving any additional info :(.

[image: instruments screenshot]

Comment: does it have a complex transform on it? frame = bounds + transformation

Comment: @Daij-Djan you think that applying CGAffineTransform's could be taking all this time? I exepcted that to be a very fast operation. Unfortunately, no "number of calls" column in Instruments when I was doing this, but I'll try again and see if I can get a count for number of calls

Answer (score 1):

The frame property is calculated. Try accessing the bounds and/or center properties instead if those are all you need.